# SnowballAnalyzer - Exact match searches

Tags: lucene.net

I'm using SnowballAnalyzer in Lucene.Net 3.0.3, and it works well for stem matches. I would like to also support exact text matches, so if a user searches for "jumping jacks", in quotes, it will only match documents which contain that exact phrase. But the index will contain only the word stems, "jump" and "jack". Is it possible to index and search the original text while still supporting stemming?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html) for indexing and searching. Add two fields, one using SnowballAnalyzer and one using StandardAnalyzer. For exact phrases, search the field you've indexed with StandardAnalyzer, and for the rest use the SnowballAnalyzer one.